# Reference request - derivation of $\mathrm{ind}\,D_+=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int\text{tr}\,F\wedge F$

Tags: resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, quantum-anomalies

Let $D$ be the Dirac operator.

The equation
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathrm{ind}\,D_+=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_M\text{tr}\,F^2=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_MF^a\wedge F^b\ \mathrm{tr}(T_aT_b)
\end{equation}
is a special case of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem (the RHS is equal to an integer, the instanton number) - see section $12.6.2$ of Mikio Nakahara's [book](https://doi.org/10.1201/9781315275826) . He also derives the equation in section $13.2.1$ (Abelian anomalies - Fujikawa's method).

I have to understand the derivation for my Bachelor thesis, but I find it very challenging to understand Nakahara's book - I prefer modern mathematical treatments of Gauge Theory (e.g. [Mark Hamilton's book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-68439-0)).

Do you know any other book containing the derivation of $(1)$? I would prefer a proper mathematical derivation, but all additional references would help. (I am not looking for a proof of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem in its most general form).

Answer (score 3):

> Do you know any other book containing the derivation of (1)? I would prefer a proper mathematical derivation, but all additional references would help.

Here's one in the "additional references" category: Fujikawa and Suzuki (2004), [*Path Integrals and Quantum Anomalies*](https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198529132.001.0001), Oxford University Press.

It includes detailed derivations of chiral anomalies using different methods, including the one that made Fujikawa famous (using a smooth mode cut-off to define the path integral Jacobian) and another one using lattice QFT, which is the first time I've seen a lattice QFT calculation of chiral anomalies in a book. It's written more for an audience of physicists than for mathematicians, but it's relatively detailed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the proof by Getzler: "A short proof of the local Atiyah-Singer Index theorem" [*Topology,* Vol 25, pages  111-117 (1986)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(86)90008-X).  That give the general case, including curved space, and in any dimension.